# Avoid & Count non-numerical values computing basic statistics in Mathematica

Tags: statistics, wolfram-mathematica, design-patterns, numerical

Please consider:

```
dalist={{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, 
       {2.88`, 2.04`, 4.64`,0.56`, 4.92`, 2.06`, 3.46`, 2.68`, 2.72`,0.820},   
       {"Laura1", "Laura1", "Laura1", "Laura1", "Laura1", 
       "Laura1", "Laura1", "Laura1", "Laura1","Laura1"}, 
       {"RIGHT", 0, 1, 15.1`, 0.36`, 505, 20.059375`,15.178125`, ".", "."}}
```

[image]

The actual dataset is about 6 000 rows and 147 columns. However the above reflects its content. I would like to compute some basic statistics, such as the mean. My attempt:

```
Table[Mean@dalist[[colNO]], {colNO, 1, 4}]
```

[image]

How could I create a function such as to:

- Avoid non-numerical values and
- Count the number of non numerical values found in each lists.

I have not succeeded in finding the right pattern mechanism yet.

Comment: Your test table is transposed with respect to the TableForm printout you provided...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First observation: you could use `Mean /@ dalist` if you wanted to average across rows. You don't need a `Table` function here.

Try using `Cases` ([documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Cases.html)), eg. `Mean /@ (Cases[#,_?NumericQ] & /@ dalist)`

If you want to be tricky and eliminate rows from your data that have no numeric elements (eg your third column), try the following. It first picks only the rows that have *some* numeric elements, and then takes only the numeric elements from those rows.

```
Mean /@ (Cases[#,_?NumericQ] & /@ (Cases[dalist, {___,_?NumericQ,___}]))
```

To count the non-numeric elements, you would use a similar approach:

```
Length /@ (Cases[#,Except[_?NumericQ]] & /@ dalist)
```

*This answer has the caveat that I typed it out without the benefit of a Mathematica installation to actually check my syntax. Some typos could remeain.*

Comment: Thank You very much ! It is perfect. And without a .nb !

Comment: Instead of `Cases` you could also use `Select[#, NumericQ] &`. The use of a test is natural for `Select` where `Case` uses patterns that in this case have to be converted to tests using `PatternTest (?)`

Comment: @Sjoerd, for some obscure resins to me, your code works with Select[#, NumericQ] &@dalist[[2]] for example. This solution seems optimal in my case, thanks.

Comment: +1 @Sjoerd - I just trust myself with `Cases` more than `Select` when typing blind :)

Comment: Alternatively, to count non-numeric terms, `Count[#, Except[_? NumericQ]] & /@ dalist`

Comment: (Modified) from Mma 7 help on the (now-obsolete?) DataManipulation package.  To get the mean of all rows **which do not contain** non-numeric data: `Mean /@ Select[dalist, VectorQ[#, NumericQ[#] &] &]`.  The original entry uses `Select[mylist, VectorQ[#, NumberQ[N[#]] &] &]`. I can't see any advantage of NumberQ[N[#]] over NumericQ[#] but perhaps there is one?

Comment: @TomD, I think this is an independent answer? OP hasn't accepted any yet so you may as well put it up as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a variation of Verbeia's answer that you may consider.

Assuming that this is a rectangular array (all rows are the same length), then setting `d` to the row length (which can be found with `Dimensions`):

```
d = 10;

{d - Length@#, Mean@#} &@Select[#, NumericQ] & /@ dalist
```

```
(* Out: *) {{0, 11/2}, {0, 2.678}, {10, Mean[{}]}, {3, 79.5282}}
```

That is, pairs of {number_of_non-numeric, average}.

`Mean[{}]` appears where there are no numeric values to average.  This could be removed from the list with `DeleteCases` but the results would no longer align with the rows of `dalist`.  I think it would be better to use something like: `/. Mean[{}] -> "NO AVERAGE"` if needed.

Answer (score 2):

The key to answering your question is the [NumberQ](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NumberQ.html) function: "*NumberQ[expr] gives True if expr is a number, and False otherwise."

To compute the mean of only numeric elements in each list:

```
Map[Function[lst, Mean[Select[lst, NumberQ]]], dalist]
```

To count the number of non-numeric elements in each list:

```
Map[Function[lst, Length[Select[lst, Function[x, !NumberQ[x]]]]], dalist]
```

Comment: `NumericQ` is usually better than `NumberQ`: consider `NumberQ[Pi]` vs. `NumericQ[Pi]`.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like in this case, only literal numbers are used, so I'll keep it at `NumberQ`.